# Android: Height of table cell should get height of previous cell

Tags: android, height, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I'm creating a `TableLayout` programmatically. A table row can consist of an amount + unit (cell 1), and ingredient (cell 2) and a delete button (cell 3).
The ingredients can be longer than the available width, so I used the weight attribute and set it to 1 to enable a line break:

```
setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

This works. 
The problem is that the delete button prevents the table row to increase the height, so it is partly hidden which looks like this:

[image: hidden row]

This is the important part of the code that produces one table row:

```
final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
tableRow.setTag(INGREDIENT_ENTRY);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// Amount and unit
int dp6InPixel = PixelCalculator.convertDpToPixel(getApplicationContext(), 6);
TextView tvAmountAndUnitText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvAmountAndUnitText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tvAmountAndUnitText.setText(strAmount + " " + strUnit);
tvAmountAndUnitText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
tvAmountAndUnitText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16f);
tvAmountAndUnitText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
tvAmountAndUnitText.setTypeface(tvAmountAndUnitText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
tvAmountAndUnitText.setPadding(dp6InPixel, 0, dp6InPixel, 0);
tableRow.addView(tvAmountAndUnitText);

// Ingredient
TextView tvIngredientText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvIngredientText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
tvIngredientText.setText(strIngredient);
tvIngredientText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
tvIngredientText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16f);
tableRow.addView(tvIngredientText);

// Button
int dp10InPixel = PixelCalculator.convertDpToPixel(getApplicationContext(), 10);
TextView tvIngredientDeleteButton = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
LayoutParams buttonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonParams.setMargins(dp10InPixel, 0, 0, 0);
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.lightred));
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f);
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setPadding(dp6InPixel, dp6InPixel, dp6InPixel, dp6InPixel);
tvIngredientDeleteButton.setText("x");
//more code

tableRow.addView(tvIngredientDeleteButton);
ingredientTable.addView(tableRow);
```

When I set `tvIngredientDeleteButton.setMinLines(2);`, then I can see the full ingredient cell. Unfortunately all rows have a min height of 2 then which looks ugly. I need some way to recognize if the ingredient cell has a line break and set `minLines` for that case or any other good solution (but I will not count ingredient characters or something. I guess this can be solved with some table attributes or similar). Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableRow is direct subclass of LinearLayout. And inorder to set how child views are positioned in it, you need to define it's gravity. Default value is TOP, and I've tried with FILL, CENTER_VERTICAL etc. So any value of setGravity() other than TOP will render TextView with full content. Please refer official [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity(int)), for more detail.

So you just need to add one statement at a time of declaration of TableRow to achieve your requirement.

```
          tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
```